# Pyrtlsdr not compatible with android

Tags: android, beeware

I built an app using Bee Ware briefcase but one dependency for this is the pyrtlsdrlib. This is not for android, I found https://github.com/keesj/librtlsdr-android, does anyone know how I can build this and call it in my python code to be used as the librtlsdr?

I built the app and works perfectly in my macmini. Once I package for android it just crashes